# Why didn't 2nd Hokage use the same underworld resurrection release jutsu which Madara used to gain control of himself?

Tags: naruto

2nd hokage was the creator of Edo Tensei(under world resurrection) so he knew everything about it. WE also know Madara gained control of himself using the "release" jutsu. So if there was certain jutsu like that the creator must know it. When Orochimaru summoned him during his fight with the third hokage he didn't do anything. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No "what if" questions are going to have definitive concrete answers, but:
[Edo Tensei](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Summoning%3a_Impure_World_Reincarnation)

It was developed by the 2nd, but it was "perfected" by Orochimaru.

That is to say: the developer of a technique is not always the one who figures it out completely. A technique is not like an invention, where you compose all the parts out of basic building blocks (though some are). So, if Orochimaru was able to do better with Edo Tensei than the 2nd (and eventually Kabuto went even further), then there should be no qualms postulating that Madara could go even further.